# How to push only one value from a hash into a new array (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, push

I've been struggling with this. I'm trying to write this blackjack game where I need to draw a random card, push it into an array, compare it against a hash which has the scores of each card and return the final score. I've written the following, however it's not drawing one card at a time.

This is the output (please note I'm `puts`ing the array instead of the final score which helped me figure out what went wrong). The random_card is a method to generate a random card which I haven't included here.
I'm pretty sure it's something to do with my score method.

```
Hit or stick?
hit
Score so far: [10]
Hit or stick?
hit
Hit or stick?
hit
Score so far: [10, 10, 10]
Hit or stick?
hit
Hit or stick?
hit
Score so far: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

This is my code

```
$score_so_far = []
$total_score = 0

def score(cards) 
  card_scores = {
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6,
    "seven" => 7,
    "eight" => 8,
    "nine" => 9,
    "ten" => 10,
    "jack" => 10,
    "queen" => 10,
    "king" => 10,
    "ace" => 11
  }
  
  cards.each do |x|
    card_scores.each do |k, v|
      if k === x
        $score_so_far.push(v)
      end
    end
  end
  $total_score = $score_so_far.sum
end

def run_game
  move = gets.chomp
  $hand = []
  while true do 
    if move == "stick"
      break
    elsif move == "hit"
      $hand << random_card 
      score($hand)
      puts "Score so far: #{$score_so_far}"
    end
  end   
  
    if $total_score <= 21
      puts "You scored: #{$total_score}"
    elsif $total_score > 21
      puts "You busted with: #{$total_score}"
    end
end
run_game
```

If anyone is able to offer some assistance, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing the concept of a deck, which would make it easy to shuffle and pop random cards. Without that, you could use [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), but it won't change the cards remaining in your deck.

Answer (score 0):

The `score` method mutating global variables every time you call it. So if you call it twice for the same card set you see different results.

```rb
def score(cards) 
  card_scores = {
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6,
    "seven" => 7,
    "eight" => 8,
    "nine" => 9,
    "ten" => 10,
    "jack" => 10,
    "queen" => 10,
    "king" => 10,
    "ace" => 11
  }

  score_so_far = []
  cards.each do |x|
    card_scores.each do |k, v|
      if k === x
        score_so_far.push(v)
      end
    end
  end
  score_so_far.sum
end
```

So instead of mutating something outside you just sum values of cards and return it.

Also you have to change `run_game` method not to global variables too:

```rb
  # ...
  current_score = 0
  while true do 
    if move == "stick"
      # ...
    elsif move == "hit"
      # ...
      current_score = score(hand)
      puts "Score so far: #{current_score}"
    end
  end   
  
    if current_score <= 21
      puts "You scored: #{current_score}"
    elsif current_score > 21
      puts "You busted with: #{current_score}"
    end
end
```

I see you changed something in the `run_game` method because calling it will cause an infinite loop.